# Trying to setup mod-security but mod-security.conf is missing

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to setup an apache2 web server on the new Ubuntu 14.04.  I have been following the instructions found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-mod_security-with-apache-on-debian-ubuntu) and everything was going great until I reached the part where I'm told to edit mod-security.conf.  This file does not exist.

The author says to edit it in the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled directory.  I think this is wrong.  I think it should be in the /etc/apache2/mods-available directory but it isn't in either place.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

```
ls /etc/apache2/mods-available/
```

security2.conf

```
sudo a2enmod security2
```

Comment: It would be great if you could edit your post to include an explanation. Code-only answers are usually not welcome.

Answer (score 0):

### First, you must reinstall it :

`sudo apt reinstall libapache2-mod-security2 -y`

### Then, enable the Apache2 headers:

`sudo a2enmod headers`

### After that, enable your ModSecurity:

`sudo a2enmod security2`

### Restart Apache2

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

## ConfigFile:

#### /etc/apache2/mods-available/security2.conf